# Joining Count and select query

Tags: sql, db2

**Table Genre**

```
 GENRE_CATEGORY     DESCRIPTION
 --------------     ----------------------
 C100           Information Technology
 C200           Novel
 C300           Cookery
 C400           Lifestyle
```

**Table Book**

```
 ISBN           TITLE               PAGE_NUMBER     PUBLICATION_YEAR    PUBLISHER_CODE  GENRE_CATEGORY
 ------------   -----------------   -----------     ----------------    --------------  --------------
 123-0-12-374   Rainbow Mountain            200              2011      P2001                 C200
 989-2-96-545   Data Mining                 340              2012      P2002            C100
 718-8-16-555   Asian Food                  280              2013      P3002            C300
 674-9-90-345   Yoga for the mind           180             2016       P2002            C400
 900-0-88-767   Finding Rainbow             250             2016       P2001            C200
 888-9-55-447   Pastry Heaven               200             2016       P3002            C300
```

what sql statement do i need to write to produce a table with publisher code, description, Number of books(count number of books using count).
The table must show how many number of books for novel , Information technology,lifestyle and cookery. I've spent two hours trying to figure out what to do please do help me

```
select Publisher_Code,Description, count(genre_category)
from genre
INNER Join book
ON genre.genre_category=book.genre_category
where(genre.genre_category=book.genre_category);
```

[The output must look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmUGJ.jpg)

Comment: Firstly, good start at your first question. However, you should include what you have attempted so far, even if it doesn't work. SO is here to help, but isn't a code writing service

Comment: sorry forgot to add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
select Publisher_Code, Description, count(*)
from genre
INNER Join book
   ON genre.genre_category=book.genre_category
GROUP BY Publisher_Code, Description;
```